# "Manipulate" html files (server-side) and insert their content in main html page (*without* PHP)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, insert, server-side

Context : I'm working on a site that runs on my university's server (IIS, not Apache), no way to use PHP.

I want the site to be so simple that people with very little HTML/CSS/js knowledge can put new content when I'll be done with it.  I'm a grad student in health sciences and I've learned HTML, CSS, etc. by myself since a few years (so I'm definitely not a pro), so pardon me if my question is a little naive.

I'd really need some script/tool that would allow me to :

- Get content from an external file (blog post) on the server (let's say a list of ".html" files located in a folder on the server, let's say the folder "/blog-posts/", containing a bunch of files named "jan-15.html", "feb-15.html", etc.)
- Pick the last 4 files (4 most recent)
- Insert this content at a precise point in a html file
- (Optional, but it would really be nice) Pull the date the file was last edited, put it in a string and insert said string before the blog post, in the home page

So :

- Do anyone know if anything like this already exists ?
- If not, do you guys think it's possible with some js/jQuery to "manipulate" external files like that ?
- If it's possible, any hints how :) ?

Thanks a million times, I know I'm asking a lot, but I've been searching for a viable solution for this for the last few months... It's my first time writing here but I've been an avid reader since a very long time.

Have a great day !

Comment: Actually you can use [php along with IIS](http://php.iis.net/). And the approach of using multiple html files for every post is ineficient. You should manage a databse with the info, for simplicity, I would suggest [wordpress](http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/install.aspx?appsxml=http%3a%2f%2fwww.microsoft.com%2fweb%2fwebpi%2f2.0%2fWebApplicationList.xml&appid=WordPress)

Answer (score -1):

You can store a simple blog configuration as a JSON object and update it as you add new posts. Let's say you have the files `jan.html` and `feb.html` in your `blog-posts` folder.

Now in the main folder, create a file `content.json` as follows this:

```
{
    "posts": [
        { "uri": "feb.html", "date": "2/12/15" },
        { "uri": "jan.html", "date": "1/3/15" }
    ]
}
```

Now you can get the blog content with AJAX requests from JavaScript. Example:

```html
<script>
  function Init(posts)
  {
    var e = document.getElementById('content');
    var s = '';
    
    posts.forEach(function(post)
    {
      console.log(post.content);
      s += '<div><h2>Date: ' + post.date + '</h2><p>' + post.content + '</p></div>';
    });
    
    e.innerHTML = s;
  }

  function LoadContent(config)
  {
    var remain = config.posts.length;
    var posts = [];
    
    config.posts.forEach(function(post) 
    {
      var req = new XMLHttpRequest();    
      
      req.open('GET', 'blog-posts/' + post.uri, true);
      req.onload  = function() 
      {
        remain--;
        posts.push({ content: req.responseText, date: post.date });
        
        if(remain === 0)
        {
          Init(posts);
        }
      };
      
      req.send(null);
    });
  }

  function LoadConfig()
  {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    
    req.open('GET', 'content.json', true);  
    req.onload  = function() 
    {
      LoadContent(JSON.parse(req.responseText));
    };
    
    req.send(null);
  }
  
  window.addEventListener('load', LoadConfig);
</script>

<div id="content"></div>
```